# Quickblox public group chat history

Tags: java, android, quickblox

How can I save chat history for public chat groups in quickblox? I set the property chatMessage.setProperty(PROPERTY_SAVE_TO_HISTORY, "1"); but it doesn't work with public groups the messages don't appear in admin panel.
Or how can I give a user the authority to join group chat without and occupant user from the group chat give him one?

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
chatMessage.setProperty(PROPERTY_SAVE_TO_HISTORY, "1");
```

How did you create this public group?

You gave to use next code:

```
QBDialog dialog = new QBDialog();
dialog.setType(QBDialogType.PUBLIC_GROUP);
...
groupChatManager.createDialog(dialog, ...
```

Comment: I created public group chats from the admin system, when I send messages on them they don't get saved although I set chatMessage.setProperty(PROPERTY_SAVE_TO_HISTORY, "1"); when I send the message, on the contrary of what happens on group chats.